# How to color the EditText focus color for API < 21?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-api-levels

I have EditTexts and they color the bottom line in primary color as you can [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Rcj.png)

I want to leave it black, so I set in my layout for the EditText:

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
```

This works nice, but I have minSDK set to 19. So I immediately get a warning that this would not work for API < 21

**How can I solve this for API 19 and API 20 as well?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a code like this, and it works for me:

`yourEditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);`

I hope it works to you

Comment: I'd rather use: `editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);`